# Measure Kernel run time in the device code in CUDA

Tags: cuda, runtime, gpu, profiling

I wonder if there is a way to measure the runtime of a kernel inside the device code. To be a little more specific, I have a kernel that I run on N blocks each with M threads, like this:

```
My_Kernel<<<N, M>>>();
```

I'm running N embarrassingly parallel simulations that are each assigned to one block of M threads. So, computations in each block are independent of other blocks. I need to measure the runtime of each block (simulation).
I would be so thankful if someone can kindly suggest a way to do so.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567736/different-timing-indicated-from-two-kind-of-timers) may be of interest.  I think there are a number of questions here on the `cuda` SO tag that talk about using `clock()` or `clock64()` to time kernel code.  If you search for them and read them, you may get more useful information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RobertCrovella! However, I read those answers and they do not respond to my question.
1- I cannot use events since I need to measure runtime of each single block.
2- clock() and clock64() do not seem to be accurate methods as they may overflow.

I wonder if there is a way to use timeoftheday() or something like that inside the device code.

Comment: `clock64()` is the most accurate possibility for device side measurement, and it will not overflow.  There are no other options in device code.